# Can't get Grails 1.1 to work with Maven 2.1

Tags: maven-2, grails

When I try to build a Grails 1.1 project with Maven 2.0.9 or 2.1, I get this error:

```
[INFO] [grails:maven-compile {execution: default}]
Running pre-compiled script
Environment set to development
Plugin [debug-1.0.2] not installed, resolving..
Reading remote plugin list ...
Plugin list file corrupt, retrieving again..
   [delete] Deleting: C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\DIGULAA\.grails\1.1\plugins-list-core.xml
      [get] Getting: http://svn.codehaus.org/grails/trunk/grails-plugins/.plugin-meta/plugins-list.xml
      [get] To: C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\DIGULAA\.grails\1.1\plugins-list-core.xml
.
      [get] last modified = Thu May 14 10:44:43 CEST 2009
Error reading remote plugin list [org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl], building locally...
Plugins list cache is corrupt [org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl]. Re-creating..
Unable to list plugins, please check you have a valid internet connection: org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Unable to start Grails

Embedded error: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Cannot get property 'plugin' on null object
```

My guess is that there is a problem with the XML parser because the plugin list file is not corrupt; Grails just can't read it and the developers swallowed the exception :(

Did anyone have the same problem? What's the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it again? I think the plugin repositories were not working a few days ago.

Comment: No, this was just a technology spike and I didn't have time to try again.